# How to build an OASIS package

Tags: ocaml, opam

I tried to build this project: https://github.com/frenetic-lang/fattire, but after installing the dependencies and running `$ make`, I  get the error `make: .\configure: Command not found`
I am using omap package manager and tried to build the project with OCaml 4.03.0.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Usually this kind of questions are off-topic for SO and should be addressed though the package issue tracker or using various discussion boards, forums, and chats that OCaml community provides, see ocaml.org for more info. I've tried to generalize your question so that other users of SO can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

To build an OASIS package from scratch issue the following commands

```
oasis setup
ocaml setup.ml -configure 
ocaml setup.ml -build
ocaml setup.ml -install
```

Usually, package maintainers make the first step themselves and commit to the repository the generated files, and often they provide a Makefile together with the `./configure` scripts. In OP case the package is broken and some pregenerated files are missing, so it is easier to build it from scratch.